# firewall-cmd do you have to add port when adding a service?

Tags: firewalld

Will adding a service with firewall-cmd automatically adds the port that a service needs? for example, when I add myservice, do I need to specify a port also? What is the purpose of --add-service if you have to add a port also?

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=myservice
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for port.

See https://firewalld.org/documentation/howto/open-a-port-or-service.html

> For most of the more important services there is already a service
>   defined in firewalld. **Then there is no need to know about the default
>   port number(s).**

Comment: so, if less known service like "myservice" then need to add port the service and the port? Sorry i put a generic service, but wanted to know if it depends on if its known services and less known services.

Comment: Your choice.  If myserviceed uses port 1234, then use `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=1234/tcp`.  Or define myserviceed via `firewall-cmd --new-service` so that any subsequent rule adding can merely reference the service name and make use of the port you've explicitly defined for myserviceed.

Comment: well, then still, need to keep tracks of all ports that is opened. so when deleting a service, still need to delete port. would've been better if purge the service, then port automatically purged without having to define a new service.

Comment: OK.  If that's a question, worth posting that as an entirely new question on StackExchange.